# Way to automatically upload files to S3 from my server

Tags: amazon-s3

I have a project to complete and I am stuck at a point. Could we upload files from our server into S3 automatically at a certain time interval?

For example: A part of the data should be uploaded and from then, for every one hour, the next set of data should get uploaded.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Follow this steps;

1. Create a script file for example name it script.sh.
2. Add this to the script.sh file and save the file

   ```
   #!/bin/bash
   aws s3 cp /local-folder-path/  s3://bucket-name`
   ```
3. Install [AWS CLI](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/installing.html#install-bundle-other-os)
4. Create a IAM user that has access to that S3 bucket and add his AWS Key and Key secret to `AWS Configure` [Link](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-chap-getting-started.html)
5. Set up a cron job for 1 hour. And you are done those files will be copied to S3 bucket each hour.

   ```
   0 */1 * * * /path-to-script-file/script.sh`
   ```

Comment: SO doesn't like lists with code blocks in them. Some sort of bug in the Markdown parsing. I fixed it as well as I could.

Comment: @ceejayoz: use a double indent to format code within lists - eight spaces instead of four. (And if you want to add a non-indented block of code immediately after a list, put a `<!-- comment -->` after the list, which resets the indentation requirement).

Comment: @halfer TIL! You rock.

Comment: No worries @ceejayoz - a consequence of doing too much editing `:-p`

Comment: if the file is in a docker container and run on Fargate, how to upload it to S3?