# Not able to upload file from server to the s3 bucket using cron

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, cron

Good afternoon, can you cast your wise eyes and brains on this issue. I'm supposed to set up a scheduled upload using AWS CLI so that cron job file that I have created, gets sent to s3 (every hour), also created earlier. Now, [I have used this guide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39578958/way-to-automatically-upload-files-to-s3-from-my-server), created script file as per below, where local folder path is where my cron job file is sitting and bucket-name is my bucket created (has been created via CLI with basic command, have not added any permissions or policies). This was saved as script.sh and since creating it, I have received 2 mails to my ec2-user with main error saying `/bin/sh: /home/ec2-user/script.sh: Permission denied`

Can someone advise on where am I making boo boo? Is it not fully configured S3? Is it incorrect naming and/or placing of the fiels in the directories on the server? Cron job that is supposed to be sending first file to s3 is `0 */1 * * * /path-to-script-file.script.sh`

Thank you very much for the help, I would really like to get this right and understand what is happening here.

Script file contains:

```
#!/bin/bash
aws s3 cp /local-folder-path/  s3://bucket-name
```

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you're running the script as `ec2-user` and don't forget to `chmod 755 PATH/TO/YOUR/SCRIPT` it.

Also, you should run the `cron` under `ec2-user` - use

```bash
sudo -u ec2-user crontab -e t
```

And try re-running the script.

Finally, make sure that your EC2 has the right role to write to S3.

Comment: H, thanks for that, I think I have made "some" progress in a sense that I am getting different error messages now. I have chmod 755'd the path, I have tried re-running he script and I have also added s3 all access role for my EC2. What I am getting now according to the latest mail is:

/home/ec2-user/script.sh: line 2: unexpected EOF while looking for matching ``'
/home/ec2-user/script.sh: line 3: syntax error: unexpected end of file

Does that mean I have to add singular ' in both, script and cron job?

Comment: No, it means your script has a syntax error. Double check your .sh file.

Comment: Moving on, I have managed to resolve syntax, next in line is this

warning: Skipping file /tmp/crontab.7WLe3k. File/Directory is not readable.
Completed 0 file(s) with ~0 file(s) remaining (calculating...)^M